# Como insertar un dato que tenga llave foránea en php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un registro de usuario en php, pero al momento de registrarlo el debe seleccionar una empresa que representa entonces en la base de datos pues la tabla usuario tiene llave foránea de empresa.

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer referencia de la llave foránea en el registro de usuario y que las empresas registradas puedan aparecer como opción en el la pagina de registro

mi código

```
$conectar = new conexion();
$conectado = $conectar->conectar();

$sql = "SELECT INTO usuarios(nombre, correo, contraseña, cedular, rol,estado) VALUE ('$nombre', '$correo', '$contraseña','$cedula','Visitante',1)";

if (mysqli_query($conectado, $sql)) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Nuevo registro creado con éxito");
          </script>';
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conectado);
}
```

La base de datos esta así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo registradas algunas empresas, pero también me gustaría saber como puedo mostrar esas empresas en la vista de registro para poder ser seleccionada y que haga referencia a las que están almacenadas en la base de datos.

Comment: La llave foránea no tiene importancia (para la vista). Tú mostrarías un `select option` (HTML) leyendo la tabla `empresas`. En el `value` de cada `option` pondrías `idempresas` de la tabla `empresas`, el cual usarás para hacer la inserción/actualización en la tabla `usuarios` (es aquí donde sí importa la llave foránea).

Comment: Si, en el lado de guardar el dato del usuario es que necesito la llave foránea, pero igualmente no he podido mostrar las opciones de empresa en el HTML para así guardarla como llave foránea en el registro

Comment: Tú tienes que hacer esta consulta: `$sql = "SELECT idempresas, nombre FROM empresas";` Leer cada fila y crear un `select` más o menos así: `<select name="empresa"><option value="1">Empresa1</option><option value="2">Empresa2</option><option value="999">Empresa999</option></select>` Eso programáticamente claro, leyendo los resultados de la consulta SQL. No sé si logro explicarme. Te aconsejaría también que no mezcles PHP/Javascript y que en cambio uses Ajax o Fetch para comunicar entre cliente y servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el contexto donde **se recogen los datos** la llave foránea no tiene ninguna utilidad, porque ahí lo que interesa es mostrar la lista de empresas para que se escoja una (o varias según el caso).

Lo propio entonces es **usar la tabla `empresas`** sin más y crear un elemento HTML del tipo `select option`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$conectar = new conexion();
$conectado = $conectar->conectar();

$sql = "SELECT idempresas, nombre FROM empresas ORDER BY nombre";

if ($rs=mysqli_query($conectado, $sql)) {
    $html="<select name=\"empresas\">";
    $html.="<option value=\"-1\" disabled>--Seleccione empresa--</option>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
        $html.=sprintf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>",$row["idempresas"], $row["nombre"]);
    }
    $html.="</select>";
} else {
    $html = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conectado);
}
echo $html;
```

Luego, en el contexto donde **se reciben los datos**, vas a tener el valor del `option` que estuviera seleccionado (el `idempresa`)  y usarás ese dato para insertarlo como llave foránea del nuevo registro o de la actualización de `usuarios`.

---

#### Recomendaciones

- Evita la mezcla de PHP y Javascript. Para comunicar entre cliente y servidor considera usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript.
- En consultas donde tengas que pasar datos que pueden ser introducidos por el usuario, considera usar consultas preparadas. Un usuario mal intencionado podría manipular los datos y causar graves daños en tu servidor o en tus datos.

Comment: Entendió un poco, me gustaría hacerle una consulta mas... 
estoy haciendo lo mismo pero en html para que se pueda seleccionar, pero creo que lo estoy haciendo mal, pero no tengo forma de mostrarte el código

Comment: aqui hice una pregunta, sobre lo que hablo por si puede ayudarme [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/512258/select-din%c3%a1mico-con-php-creo-que-tengo-errores)