# select dinámico con php, creo que tengo errores

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando hacer un select dinámico trayendo datos de la base de datos específicamente de la tabla empresas, pero igual aun no me muestra los datos

codigo:

```
<label for="empresa">Empresa a la que respresenta</label>
                        <select name="empresa" id="">
                            <?php
                                include '..php/conexion.php';
                                $conectar = new conexion();
                                $conectado = $conectar->conectar();

                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM empresas";
                                $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conectado, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conectado));
                                
                            ?>
                            <php foreach($ejecutar as $valor):?>

                                <option value="<?php echo $valor['idempresas']?>"><?php echo $valor['nombre']?></option>    

                            <php endforeach; ?>


                            
                        </select>
```

no se que estoy haciendo mal realmente para que no me muestre valor aun

Comment: Te falta obtener los datos como un **array asociativo**, podrías hacer algo como ```while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ejecutar)) {  echo $row['idempresas'];   }```, aquí puedes ver un ejemplo en el manual: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: en este caso donde iría ese fragmento de código

Comment: Va gusta después de tu línea ```$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conectado, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conectado));``` y añades despues el ```while() {}```

Comment: No me funciono, no se que estoy colocando mal pero nada me termina funcionando en ese apartado

Comment: Haz esto y nos muestras el resultado `var_dump($ejecutar);`

Comment: @DjCrazy no me muestra nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un posible ejemplo para orientarte un poco.

Comprueba también que tu conexión este funcionado correctamente, ya que no vemos tu clase conexión.

Si no lo pruebas con este código:

*Posible conexión:*

```
$conectado = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "tu_base_de_datos");

/* verificar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

**Un posible ejemplo:**

```
// Incluyes tu conexión o usas la conexion del ejemplo
include '..php/conexion.php';
$conectar = new conexion();
$conectado = $conectar->conectar();


// Reset
$options = ''; // Va devolver tus options html ¡important! resetearlo

// Sentencia
$sql = "SELECT * FROM empresas";

// Ejecutar consulta
if ($ejecutar = mysqli_query($conectado, $sql)) {

    /* determinar el número de filas del resultado */
    $numero_de_filas = mysqli_num_rows($ejecutar);
    // Existen filas
    if ($numero_de_filas > 0) {
        /* obtener array asociativo */
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ejecutar)) {
            // Creamos options html
            $options .= "<option value='{$row['idempresas']}'>{$row['nombre']}</option>";
        }

        /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
        mysqli_free_result($ejecutar);
    // No existe resultado
    } else {
        echo 'No se encontraron registros';
    }

} else {
    echo 'No se pudo ejecutar la consulta.';
    // Imprimir fallo mysqli_error
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conectado));
}

?>

<label for="empresa">Empresa a la que respresenta</label>
    <select name="empresa" id="">
        <?php echo $options ?>
    </select>
</label>
```

[Manual: mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)
[Manual: mysqli_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Y realmente te aconsejo a usar [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php), que son mucho más seguras.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya logre que funcionara. MIL GRACIAS!!

Comment: Me alegro amigo. Un saludo 